# How to find out whole statistics about age of users which use my app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-play, firebase-analytics

So in Google Play I have the next target audience for my app:

[image]

But when I go to Firebase Analytics or Google Analytics website and check statistics for this app it doesn't allow me to see age below 18:

[image]

How am I supposed to know which full audience use my app? It can show only statistics about adults..

Comment: You are not supposed to get information on minors (which in many legislations is not even legal), especially not in a context where you might use the information to target audiences. That is why it is not in there.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I just want to understand if my is being used by children or only by adults?